# Run sed without -n, will the d command skip the default auto print pattern space content?

Tags: sed

The document of `sed` states that `d` will:

> Delete the pattern space; immediately start next cycle.

If `sed` is run without `-n`, will `sed` auto print the pattern space after a `d` command? I know at this situation, the pattern space is empty. So it's no differences to print or not. But I'm just curious.

I have this example:

```
root@u1804:~# seq 10 | sed -r '/5/d'
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
root@u1804:~#
```

As you can see, there is no `5`. It's because the `d` caused the execution directly to the next cycle or the auto print pattern space prints an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `d` restarts the cycle so no auto-printing. It's easy to see that if you attempt to append to the pattern space after a `d` command e.g via `G` or `s/^/STUFF/` nothing gets printed...
Try `seq 3 | sed '1h;2d;2G'` - it will not print `1` twice even though you save it via `1h` and then try to append it via `2G` for the simple reason the last command is never executed - everything that follows after `d` (including auto-printing) is ignored (for the current address, that is).
[The standard is pretty clear](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13):

> If no commands explicitly started a new cycle, then at the end of the
>   script the pattern space shall be copied to standard output (except
>   when `-n` is specified) and the pattern space shall be deleted.

It's also in [the manual that you quoted:](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Overview.html#Overview)

> By default sed prints all processed input (except input that has been
>   modified/deleted by commands such as `d`)